# convert character to percentage R

Tags: r

I have data from csv and I would like to create third column by multiply discount * price in dataframe.
Column discount it is a character and price it is integer.
How can I multiply this column in R?

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do when the discount column is blank?

Comment: When discount is blank it means there wan no discount

Comment: So no discount can be interpreted as 0 discount, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
df %>% mutate(D = as.numeric(parse_number(Discount))) %>% mutate(Discount_Amount = case_when(is.na(D) ~ 0, TRUE ~ (D/100)*Price)) %>% select(-D)
  Discount Price Discount_Amount
1      10%    10             1.0
2             20             0.0
3       5%    30             1.5
```

Data used:

```
df
  Discount Price
1      10%    10
2             20
3       5%    30
>
```